# Plotting figure side by side and numbering them using subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot two figure side by side using subfigure. However, the figures are coming one below another instead of side by side and also the caption is printed twice for each o the figure! I have mentioned the code below. Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

```
\documentclass[standalone]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
 \centering   
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .50]

\begin{axis}[ 
    %width = 8cm , 
    %height = 10cm,
    symbolic x coords={$\tau =5$,$\tau = 10$,$\tau =15$,$\tau =20$, $\tau =25$},
    xtick={$\tau =5$,$\tau =15$, $\tau =25$},
    %x tick label style={
    %/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel= $\mathcal{R}_{\min}$,
    ytick ={0.1,0.2,...,3},
    xlabel = Size of the Time Window  \\  (a),
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    %legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    legend style={at={(0.65,0.9)},
    anchor=south,legend columns=5},
    ybar,
    bar width=5.8pt,]

\addplot[style={fill=red,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.313) ($\tau =15$,0.278)
($\tau =25$,0.284) };\addlegendentry{run=1}

\addplot[style={fill=green,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.119) ($\tau =15$,0.1143)
($\tau =25$,0.103) };\addlegendentry{run=2}

\addplot[style={fill=blue,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.001) ($\tau =15$,0.001)
($\tau =25$,0.001) };\addlegendentry{run=3}

%\legend{Far,Near}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{(a)}
\label{fig:sub1}

\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .50]

\begin{axis}[ 
    %width = 8cm , 
    %height = 10cm,
    symbolic x coords={$\tau =5$,$\tau = 10$,$\tau =15$,$\tau =20$, $\tau =25$},
    xtick={$\tau =5$,$\tau =15$, $\tau =25$},
    %x tick label style={
    %/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel= $\mathcal{R}_{\min}$,
    ytick ={0.1,0.2,...,3},
    xlabel = Size of the Time Window  \\  (a),
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    %legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    legend style={at={(0.65,0.9)},
    anchor=south,legend columns=5},
    ybar,
    bar width=5.8pt,]

\addplot[style={fill=green,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.313) ($\tau =15$,0.278)
($\tau =25$,0.284) };\addlegendentry{run=1}

\addplot[style={fill=red,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.119) ($\tau =15$,0.1143)
($\tau =25$,0.103) };\addlegendentry{run=2}

\addplot[style={fill=blue,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.001) ($\tau =15$,0.001)
($\tau =25$,0.001) };\addlegendentry{run=3}

%\legend{Far,Near}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{(b)}
\label{fig:sub2}

\end{subfigure}

\caption{(a) Clustering using the K-means algorithm, (b) Clustering using KMEC algorithm, $N = 30, M = 3, r_{\max} = 10$.}
\end{figure}






\end{document}
```

What I want is basically something similar to the below sample image.

[image]

Comment: Remove the blank line between the two `subfigure` environments

Comment: Tried that but the problem still remains.

Comment: Remove all blanklines and set the width to, say, `0.48\linewidth`. For the captions, just use `\caption{}`. Numbering is automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some missunderstandings.  Please see the following changed code.  I used package `showframe` to visualize the resulting typing area, package `blindtext` to create some dummy text and command `\fbox{...}` to visualize the resulting subfigure.  To get  a left justified first subfigure and a right justified second subfigure I added command `\hfill` between both subfigures.

At last I played with the columnwidth for both subfigures. I set it to `.45\linewidth` to have a small gap between both sub figures.  see that I also changed the `scale = .50` for the second subfigure. See the resulting smaller image in the resulting pdf file.

With the following changed MWE:

```
\documentclass[standalone]{article}

\usepackage[%
  margin=20pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,hang
]{caption} % <==========================================
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{blindtext,showframe} % <====================================


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering   
\fbox{% to visualize resulting picture with surrounding line ...
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .50]
\begin{axis}[%
    %width = 8cm , 
    %height = 10cm,
    symbolic x coords={$\tau =5$,$\tau = 10$,$\tau =15$,$\tau =20$, $\tau =25$},
    xtick={$\tau =5$,$\tau =15$, $\tau =25$},
    %x tick label style={
    %/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel= $\mathcal{R}_{\min}$,
    ytick ={0.1,0.2,...,3},
    xlabel = Size of the Time Window  \\  (a),
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    %legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    legend style={at={(0.65,0.9)},
    anchor=south,legend columns=5},
    ybar,
    bar width=5.8pt,
]

\addplot[style={fill=red,mark=none}]
  coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.313) ($\tau =15$,0.278)
($\tau =25$,0.284) };\addlegendentry{run=1}

\addplot[style={fill=green,mark=none}]
  coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.119) ($\tau =15$,0.1143)
($\tau =25$,0.103) };\addlegendentry{run=2}

\addplot[style={fill=blue,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.001) ($\tau =15$,0.001)
($\tau =25$,0.001) };\addlegendentry{run=3}
%\legend{Far,Near}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Clustering using the K-means algorithm}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}% no empty line after this line
}% end \fbox{
\hfill% <===============================================================
\fbox{
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth} % \textwidth
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .45]

\begin{axis}[ 
    %width = 8cm , 
    %height = 10cm,
    symbolic x coords={$\tau =5$,$\tau = 10$,$\tau =15$,$\tau =20$, $\tau =25$},
    xtick={$\tau =5$,$\tau =15$, $\tau =25$},
    %x tick label style={
    %/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel= $\mathcal{R}_{\min}$,
    ytick ={0.1,0.2,...,3},
    xlabel = Size of the Time Window  \\  (a),
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    %legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
    legend style={at={(0.65,0.9)},
    anchor=south,legend columns=5},
    ybar,
    bar width=5.8pt,]

\addplot[style={fill=green,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.313) ($\tau =15$,0.278)
($\tau =25$,0.284) };\addlegendentry{run=1}

\addplot[style={fill=red,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.119) ($\tau =15$,0.1143)
($\tau =25$,0.103) };\addlegendentry{run=2}

\addplot[style={fill=blue,mark=none}]
coordinates {($\tau =5$,0.001) ($\tau =15$,0.001)
($\tau =25$,0.001) };\addlegendentry{run=3}
%\legend{Far,Near}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Clustering using KMEC algorithm, $N = 30, M = 3, r_{\max} = 10$}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
}
\caption{(a) Clustering using the K-means algorithm, (b) Clustering using KMEC algorithm, $N = 30, M = 3, r_{\max} = 10$.}
\label{fig:completefigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

If you do not want an complete caption for the subfigures just write only `\caption{}`.

Does that help you?